# Meteor + React + createContainer - User Profile Lookup

Tags: reactjs, meteor

Is it possible to find user and grab info this way? I'm getting `unidentified` when trying to

```
console.log(this.props.userDetails)
```

Here is my createContainer config

```
export default createContainer(() => {

  const userDetails = Meteor.users.find({ _id: 'WSLuMFqofmks5i99F'  }).fetch().profile

  return { userDetails };
}, userProfile);
```

Assuming that a valid ID will be passed and results will be available as props to userProfile component

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean `undefined`? 
The exact error message would be helpful.

You could use `findOne()` instead of `find()` and `fetch()` (just for convenience).

This line of code:

```
const userDetails = Meteor.users.find({ _id: 'WSLuMFqofmks5i99F'  }).fetch().profile
```

Assumes that there is a user with that _id. Better defensive code would be:

```
export default createContainer(() => {
  const user = Meteor.users.findOne({ _id: 'WSLuMFqofmks5i99F'  })
  if (!user) throw new Meteor.error("Could not find user")
  return {userDetails: user.profile}
}, userProfile);
```

Then you could see what the error is

Comment: Correct answer, you may also explain, that `find()` returns a cursor to all found documents from the query. Calling `fetch()` on that cursor creates an array of the documents, the is cursor pointing to. Noe calling `.profile()` on that array returns (understandably) `undefined`. Just to make OP understand how this `undefined` is created and what the underlying mechanisms are.